# How to make FFmpeg continuously write progress on one line

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, console

When encoding FFmpeg prints a new line every second with the progress, example

```
frame=   31 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=     152kB time=00:00:00.72 bitrate=1726.3kbits/s
frame=   59 fps= 57 q=0.0 size=     175kB time=00:00:01.90 bitrate= 751.1kbits/s
frame=   89 fps= 58 q=0.0 size=     204kB time=00:00:03.04 bitrate= 549.8kbits/s
```

With a large file these lines can quickly fill the console screen. I would like to see the progress on one line if possible, that is to say each second the same line is overwritten with the updated progress.

[`ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/ticket/2349`](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/ticket/2349)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least with Windows, FFmpeg requires 85 columns to
print progress correctly. I set this using the registry

```
sp hkcu:console WindowSize 0x00190055 -t dword
sp hkcu:console ScreenBufferSize 0x03e80055 -t dword
```